# (import path does not begin with hostname)

Tags: go, travis-ci

My demo golang project is https://github.com/aQuaYi/demoGolangProjectWithCI

demoGolangProjectWithCI/subModel/subModelAdd.go is

```
package subModel

import (
    "demoGolangProjectWithCI"
)

//Add returns sum of a and b
func Add(a, b int) int {
    return demoGolangProjectWithCI.Add(a, b)
}
```

and my .travis.yml is

```
language: go

go:
  - 1.8.3

script: go test ./...
```

but travis said me "package demoGolangProjectWithCI: unrecognized import path "demoGolangProjectWithCI" (import path does not begin with hostname)"

detail is https://travis-ci.org/aQuaYi/demoGolangProjectWithCI/builds/247416861

How Could I fix this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just stick to https://golang.org/doc/code.html

Answer (score 2):

`demoGolangProjectWithCI` is not resolved from `subModel` because import `"demoGolangProjectWithCI"` mean absolute path. You can write relative path like `./demoGolangProjectWithCI`. But, in generally, you've better to write full-github-paths as `github.com/aQuaYi/demoGolangProject` since your package may be used by other one's project.

Comment: Yes, After move $GOPATH/src/demoGolangProjectWithCI to $GOPATH/src/github.com/aQuaYi/demoGolangProjectWithCI. I fix it, thank you very much.